# Find out current component when ECL GetItem() is called on component localisation

Tags: ecl, blueprint, component

I have noticed that when a component is localised, the GetItem(IEclUri) method is called on the ECL ProviderContext. In that method, I make a call to an external API using metadata of the current publication.
However, if that call returns nothing, I need to perform that call again but using publication metadata of the publication owning the component being localised. However, I am unable to find a way to get to this information in the ProviderContext. The method only gets passed a IEclUri, which just contains the current publication ID. But I would like to know the current component being used (localised), so that I can get to its owning publication and use its metadata. Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the stub component URI from within GetItem.

There are a couple of workarounds that might work depending on your situation.

**Persisting the stub URL**

When the stub is being created you will receive a call to `IContextLibraryContext.StubComponentCreated`. If you have means of storing this URI (forexample as metadata on the external system you can retrieve it as needed.

**Calling a custom method on the provider.**

`IContextLibraryContext.GetItem` is called on a lot of occasions, not just when an item is being localized. If you need something to happen on localize only you can implement a Tridion event handler executing when the item is being localized. You can then use `IDispatchHandler.Dispatch` to make a custom call to the provider where you include any information you want.

Both `IContentLibraryContext` and `IContentLibraryListItem` inherits from the `IDispatchHandler` interface, allowing you to make the `Dispatch` call to your provider in general, or to a specific item.